# swift type class has no member function

Tags: swift, function, class, variables, parameters

I have created this function sayHello which is called every 4 seconds. The code for this is:

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.sayHello(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
func sayHello(Enem: SKSpriteNode) {
}
```

However when i add a variable Enem to this function:

```
 _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.sayHello(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
sayHello()

}
func sayHello() {

    let array = [Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 2"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 1"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 3"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 4"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 5"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 6"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 7"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 8"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 9"),Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 10")]
    var level0 = Enemy(imageNamed: "Slide 1")
    let level2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 2")
    let level3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 3")
    let level4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 4")
    let level5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 5")
    let level6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 6")
    let level7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 7")
    let level8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 8")
    let level9 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 9")
    let level10 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slide 10")
    var touchLocation = CGPoint?()
    var slide = arc4random_uniform(10)
    let level1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    let Enem = array[level1]
    //moveEnem(Enem)
    (string: "\(level1)")

    print("sayhdkl")
    Enem.position = CGPoint(x: 540, y: 320 )
    Enem.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: Enem.texture!, size: Enem.size)
    Enem.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Enem.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.level1
    Enem.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    Enem.zPosition = 12
    addChild(Enem)
```

I get an error on the line

`_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.sayHello(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

It says Type game scene has no member sayHello. Can someone explain why this now happens as i am very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your selector syntax, your function has no parameter so you need to write selector like this.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.sayHello()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Yes this works although there is just a new error:                                                                                                          "use of instance member sayHello on type gameScene did you mean to use value a value of type gameScene instead"

Comment: on "GameScene" in the NSTimer

Comment: Try like this `#selector(GameScene.sayHello)`